# Why is the % saved only displayed for some refurbished products?

Tags: hardware, apple-store

I was browsing the listing for the refurbished iMacs and noticed that some of the items explicitly state how much is being saved while others do not.  While it is easy to calculate the savings yourself, I wondered if there was some underlying reason for this.

[image]

Comment: I'll run this by another mod to be sure I'm not overly harsh, but this seems to beg the larger question "… for what?" What problem are you trying to solve other than "I'm looking for someone at Apple to explain why they do X"

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is understanding whether or not there is something different about the products that are listed differently so I can make better purchasing decisions.  I'm new to Ask Different so I'm fine with my question not being good if that's the case but I don't quite understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: Please upload a screen shot of what specifically you see. My brain didn't grasp that twist on your question. Just press the edit button and add a link and then comment here again @bmike - also, closing is actually to protect the question from crazy guess answers that will sink it for good. I'd rather work things out and then open it so it has a chance to get good answers. Welcome to the site - I'll do whatever I can to help get this in shape and reopened.

Comment: Wow - this is actually a good hardware shopping question. It's clear what's got you confuzzled, it documents the issue succinctly. If/when someone steps up with a good explanation - it might help others learn how Apple markets it's products to us.

Answer (score 2):

I believe those entries for which percentages are not shown are build-to-order models. Of course there was an original retail price so there's no reason *why* the percentage saving isn't shown, but Apple has decided not to display it for some reason.

Comment: Nice catch on the CTO theory. I don't see any reason why this isn't a good filter on what products are "% off" and others are not.